# Initializing Activiti process variables in XML process definition

Tags: business-process-management, activiti

Currently i have to define each process variable before execution of the process and pass it to the `startProcessInstanceBy*` functions of Activiti. I wonder if it's possible to define these with default values in the process definition XML? This way i can avoid changing Java code if my process needs new variables for execution. Can i achieve this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `script task` just after your start event to set up these variables

Comment: That's the only solution i've found aswell.